# Difference between network dataset and geometric network in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, network-dataset

In ArcGIS Desktop, what is the difference between a "network dataset" and a "geometric network"?

Are there differences with what can be done with each?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The geometric network is used to model things like utility networks, drainage, or any other network where the commodity does not have free will.

Network dataset is used for networks where "an agent" can choose the path, such as transportation networks.

There a description here (scroll down to the **What is a network?** section):
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004700000001000000.htm

> **Geometric networks (utility and river networks)**
>   River networks and utility
>   networks—like electrical, gas, sewer,
>   and water lines—allow travel on edges
>   in only one direction at a time. The
>   agent in the network—for instance, the
>   oil flowing in a pipeline—can't choose
>   which direction to travel; rather, the
>   path it takes is determined by
>   external forces: gravity,
>   electromagnetism, water pressure, and
>   so on. An engineer can control the
>   flow of the agent by controlling how
>   external forces act on the agent.
>
> **Network datasets (transportation networks)**
>   Transportation
>   networks—like street, pedestrian, and
>   railroad networks—can allow travel on
>   edges in both directions. The agent on
>   the network—for instance, a truck
>   driver traveling on roads—is generally
>   free to decide the direction of
>   traversal as well as the destination.

Comment: Is there anything about these definitions that differs from the centuries-old conventional terms "directed graph" and "undirected graph"?

Comment: Geometric networks must be 100% directed. Network datasets are typically partly directed.

Comment: Big +1, I never understood the difference.